# Organization administration portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I need to add portlet for organizations members and administrators. I have organization as a root and other organization inherited from it, it must done by a hook or what?

My second question I have added custom field "arabic name textfield" inside details section successfully but failed in making them required sections (validation) and not accept Arabic language

thank you

EDIT

I have added organization of many types from control panel I need to add a portlet for users in the organizations with their own roles without using control panel "users of organizations and administrators of organizations see a portlet to manage ...."

The second one I need to validate a custom field of organization form like name or email address.

Comment: Questions are not so clear to understand..

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.